# PayPal Sandbox returns Invalid - IPN verification

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I need some help with PAYPAL IPN system . I am completely lost.

I setup this form

```
<form class="checkout-form" name="checkout-form" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="POST"><ul class="notices-box"></ul><div class="row"><div class="col-md-8"><h2>Order Details</h2><div class="setting"><div class="setting-label"></div><input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name..."/></div><div class="setting"><div class="setting-label"></div><input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name..."/></div><div class="setting"><div class="setting-label"></div><input type="text" name="user_address" placeholder="Address..."/></div><div class="setting"><div class="setting-label"></div><input type="text" name="user_country" placeholder="Country..."/></div><div class="setting"><div class="setting-label"></div><input type="text" name="user_telephone" placeholder="Telephone..."/></div><div><input type="hidden" name="action" value="checkout"/>
<button name="submit" class="button-primary button-primary-for-checkout" style="width: auto; ">Place Order</button>
</div></div><!--end .part1.1-->
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" name="cmd" value="_notify-validate">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="return" value="http://zoomthe.me/paypalipn/paypal_ipn.php"><INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="zoomitflash-buyer-1@gmail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="zoomitflash-facilitator-1@gmail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="hat">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="15">
</form>
```

Here - http://zoomthe.me/soundportal//index.php?page=checkout

But when accesing the paypal site I get a big INVALID :(

What should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have invalid fields inside paypal form! Some invalid fields like first_name, last_name ... etc. The form must be clear, clean and correct. Use this example

```
<form method="post" name="checkout-form" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="your@paypal_email.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Product Name>
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="22" >
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="65">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="CUSTOM_CODE_@#!#!@#@!WDASD">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://zoomthe.me/paypalipn/paypal_ipn.php">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://zoomthe.me/paypal_cancel">
<input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="Product Description">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://zoomthe.me/your_listener_ipn_file.php">
</form>
```